# What are the jars required for Class mediator

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-esb

i wish insert the values in table with transaction roll back
so i am using wso2esb4.7.0. for this i wish to write class mediator i am getting errors in java while writing the code 
error is 
esb is not working for transaction rollback option my code is

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse"
          name="JmsStore_Seq"
          trace="disable">
   <property name="FORCE_ERROR_ON_SOAP_FAULT" value="true"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="Authentication"
             expression="//Authentication/text()"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="UserId"
             expression="//UserId/text()"
             scope="default"
             type="STRING"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="WorkOUid"
             expression="//WorkOUid/text()"/>
   <property xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
             name="WorkPartyBranchId"
             expression="//WorkPartyBranchId/text()"/>

   <filter xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"
           xpath="get-property('Authentication')=''">
      <then>
         <payloadFactory>
            <format>
               <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                  <Exception>Service trying to connect inactive service</Exception>
                  <Status>101503</Status>
               </ResponseJSON>
            </format>
            <args/>
         </payloadFactory>
         <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <send/>
      </then>
      <else>
         <filter xpath="get-property('Authentication')='false'">
            <then>
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Exception>Authentication Failed</Exception>
                        <Status>401</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <property name="HTTP_METHOD" value="POST" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
               <send/>
            </then>
            <else>

               <property name="jmspayload"
                         expression="get-property('readingspayload')"
                         type="OM"/>
               <property name="ResponseJSON" expression="$body/ResponseJSON" type="OM"/>

               <property name="jmsuri" expression="get-property('jmsuri')"/>
               <property name="jmsqueue" expression="get-property('jmsqueue')"/>

               <payloadFactory >
                <format>
                    <PLData>                    
                      <JMpayload>$1</JMpayload> 
                      <AuthData>$2</AuthData>  
                    </PLData>                   
                </format>
                <args>

                    <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('jmspayload')" />
                    <arg xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" expression="get-property('ResponseJSON')"/>
                </args>
                </payloadFactory>               


               <class name="in.youtility.esb.custommediators.JMSStoreMediator" />
               <payloadFactory>
                  <format>
                     <ResponseJSON xmlns="">
                        <Body>
                           <Datalist>
                              <Data>Successfully stored</Data>
                           </Datalist>
                        </Body>
                        <Status>200</Status>
                     </ResponseJSON>
                  </format>
                  <args/>
               </payloadFactory>
               <header name="To" action="remove"/>
               <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
               <property name="RESPONSE" value="true"/>
               <send/>
            </else>
         </filter>
      </else>
   </filter>
   <description/>
</sequence>
```

and i am writing for this java class but i could not find jar files where can i found this
Thanks 
Faisal

Answer (score 1):

If you need to write a class mediator, you can follow this link. It describes all the step to create your jar file and install it in the ESB.

http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/10-minute-tutorial-for-extending-wso2.html

Answer (score 0):

The most easy extensible recommended way to have DB transactions in ESB is to use WSO2 DSS inside ESB. You can very easily write data service to insert data to DB. And use ESB transaction mediator [1] to achieve transactions.

[1] - http://docs.wso2.org/display/ESB470/Transaction+Mediator

Comment: but i am using 2 proxys for single transaction can we set transaction mediator for 2 proxys